# Asynchronous call results in empty UICollectionView Cells: IOS/objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I know this is an old question but none of the answers solves my problem. I have tried reloading the UICollectoinView but even that doesn't seem to work. Please look into below code for any solutions.

I'm calling a URL to parse JSON data, which happens to be an array of **restaurants**. Stored these onto an **NSMutableArray** variable, while in asynchronous JSON request. I'm calling **URLCall** from **viewDidLoad** method.

```
- (void) URLCall
{
NSString *urlString = @"http://SomeURL/restaurants.json";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error) {
                               NSError* parseError;
                               id parse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];                                   
                               _restaurantData = [parse objectForKey:@"restaurants"];
                               NSLog(@"%@", _restaurantData);
                               [_collectionView reloadData]; //doesn't reload UICollectionView
                           }
                       }];
_name = [_restaurantData valueForKey:@"name"];
_category = [_restaurantData valueForKey:@"category"];
_imageURL = [_restaurantData valueForKey:@"backgroundImageURL"];
}
```

**restaurantData** is loaded with the JSON data. Below code shows

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [_restaurantData count];
}
```

here the **count** returned is 0. I tried having breakpoints at **return [_restaurantData count];** and **NSLog(@"@", _restaurantData);** where, the return statement is getting executed first. I'm understanding how **Asynchronous JSON** call works. I'm sure lot of people faced similar problems. A little help would be appreciated.

Note: I tried all these below methods which didn't work. 
1. Tried Reloading UIcollectionView immediately after loading the array object.
2. Tried Reloading UICollectionView inside ViewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear, didn't work.

This whole loading of data onto UICollectionView works fine if use Synchronous call.

Comment: _restaurantData got values?

Comment: Yes, it's empty at first but then after the asynchronous call happens it gets populated with the required data.

Comment: Does it go to `numberOfItemsInSection ` after call `[_collectionView reloadData];`? Try to put `[_collectionView reloadData];` in `dispatch_asyn` with main_queue